# Set fetched data as options on nuxt.config

Tags: nuxt.js, strapi, nuxtjs3, nuxt-i18n, nuxt-strapi

I'm working with nuxt 3, is there any way in which I can automatically set options for a module?

I want to fetch the active locales and the default locale I set up in Strapi, and automatically set those in the i18n module.

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/i18n',
    '@nuxtjs/strapi'
  ],
  i18n: {
    strategy: 'prefix_except_default',
    locales: [ // locales would be fetched from Strapi endpoint
      {
        code: 'en',
        file: 'en.json'
      },
      {
        code: 'it',
        file: 'it.json'
      },
    ],
    langDir: 'assets/i18n',
    defaultLocale: 'en', // default locale would be fetched from Strapi endpoint
  },
})
```

I tried to import them with a plugin, but I can't sort it out, I guess there are better methods to do what I need to do

Comment: So your app will be every http call run build command and when it will build then run server and answer a user call?

Comment: It would be every time I run the server fetches automatically the locale list and the default locale I set in the CMS

Comment: nuxt.config file is consumed during building project when you are creating server file. You need to create your own server file, so it will fetch client request to get his language preferences than build Nuxt 3 project and again server file need to consume request to render and send response to client.

Comment: You can always save in some temporary file user request then close your server and `npm run build` project, so it can fetch user preferred language together with building correct server file that can render and response files to user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine i18n plugin with pinia store.

`stores/index.js`

```js
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { useFetch } from "#app";
    
const fetchDataByLocale = async (locale, headers) => {
    const res = await useFetch('http://<STRAPI_URL>/api/posts', {
        headers,
        params: {
            locale
        }
    });

    if (res.error.value) {
        throw createError({
            statusCode: res.error.value.statusCode,
            statusMessage: res.error.value.statusMessage
        });
    }

    return res.data;
};

export const useStore = defineStore("store", {
    state: () => ({
        data: {
            en: [],
            it: []
        }
    }),
    actions: {
        async fetchData() {
            const token = "<STRAPI_TOKEN>";
            const headers = {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            };

            this.data.en = await fetchDataByLocale('en', headers);
            this.data.it = await fetchDataByLocale('it', headers);

        }
    },
    getters: {
        getData(state) {
            return state.data;
        }
    }
});
```

`plugins/i18n.ts`

```js
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
import { useStore } from '~/stores/index.js'
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';

export default defineNuxtPlugin(async ({ vueApp }) => {
    const store = await useStore();
    await store.fetchData();
    const locales = storeToRefs(store.getData);
    const defaultLocale = "en"
    const i18nInstance = createI18n({
        legacy: false,
        globalInjection: true,
        locale: defaultLocale,
        locales: locales
    });
    vueApp.use(i18nInstance);
});
```

`sampleComponent.vue`:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <button @click="changeLocale('en')">English</button>
        <button @click="changeLocale('it')">Italian</button>
        <pre>{{ currentData }}</pre>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { useStore } from '~/stores/index.js';
export default {
    setup() {
        const store = useStore();
        const currentLocale = ref('en');
        store.fetchData();
        const changeLocale = (locale) => {
            currentLocale.value = locale;
        };
        const currentData = computed(() => store.data[currentLocale.value]);
        return {
            currentData,
            changeLocale
        };
    }
};
</script>
```